# How to "animate" an element(bullet) to follow a path to another element(target) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate an image to follow the shortest path to another element after clicking on another element.

How to do that? Is there already some handy jquery library for this?

What I mean? Imagine a bullet(image) following the shortest path toward the target(div)

I have this HTML code:

```
<style>
    .click-me { 
       display: block; 
       float: left; 
       position: relative;
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
    }
    .image-will-go-after-me-after-click { 
       display: block; 
       float: left; 
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 50px;
       height: 50px;
       background: red;
    }
</style>

<img class="click-me" src="bullet.png">
<div class="image-will-go-after-me-after-click">
     <img class="i-will-be-hit" src="target.png">
</div>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to make a video game in jQuery? Finding the shortest path is always gonna be a straight line from A to B, so basic 2d algebra will apply here.  If you really must use jQuery and DOM (i would highly suggest using javascript and HTML5 canvas) then I would say you need to do the algebra in jquery to identify the slope and vector of travel, and loop your element gradually moving along that calculated slope, to a certain calculated distance.  But... please... consider other options.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :

```
// js :
$('.click-me').click(function() {
    var target_top = $('.i-will-be-hit').offset().top;
    var target_left = $('.i-will-be-hit').offset().left;
    $(this).animate({
        'top': target_top + 'px',
        'left' : target_left + 'px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: you will need jQuery